# Python Regex pattern/function not retrieving the data from my datastring

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to pull certain parts out of a string using various regexs on continuously changing data strings.

For example the two regex's below should be ONLY pulling: `Example $00.00` and `bla $00.00`

```
data = "Maybe Example $00.00 test $00.00 bla $00.00 dasdsadasd"
pull1 = re.match(r'^(Example) (\D\w+\D\w+)', data)
pull2 = re.match(r'^(bla) (\D\w+\D\w+)', data)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: What are they pulling then?

Comment: It returns `None` when it clearly exists in my code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want extract a partial string, use 'search' instead of 'match'.
This code works fine:

```
data = "Maybe Example $00.00 test $00.00 bla $00.00 dasdsadasd"
pull1 = re.search(r'(Example) (\D\w+\D\w+)', data)
pull2 = re.search(r'(bla) (\D\w+\D\w+)', data)

print pull1.group(0)
print pull2.group(0)
```

I've removed '^' from your regex.

Good luck!

Comment: Works great, thank you ever so much. Green tick will be awarded in 5mins :)

Answer (score 3):

`match()` constrains matches to start at the beginning of the string (see the docs).  You want `search()` instead.  And you don't want `^` at the start of your regexp either:  that **also** forces the match to start at the beginning of the string.  Your patterns can't match starting at the beginning of your `data` string.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `\b((Example|bla)\s\$(\d{2})\.\3)\b`

- `\b` - Begin word boundary
- `(` - Begin match #1
- `(Example|bla)` - Match #2
- `\s` - Space
- `\$` - Dollar sign
- `(\d{2})` - Match #3: 2 digits
- `\.` - Decimal place
- `\3` - Repeat match #3
- `)` - End match #1
- `\b` - End word boundary

See it in action: [RegexPal](http://tinyurl.com/kje2v3v)

Comment: Thank you ever so much for explaining that regex, that's actually really really helpful for me (I struggle with regex's)

Comment: Of course, you can change it to `\b((Example|bla)\s\$\d+\.\d{2})\b`, because the dollar amount may exceed $99.99

Answer (score 3):

re.match() matches the pattern at the beginning of the string. If you want it to recognize patterns anywhere in the string, use search() instead of match(). Also, the use of ' ^ ' in search restricts it to the beginning of the string.

In your example, you are trying to match 'Example' at the beginning of the string, which returns None as it is not found. Check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for more info!

Answer (score 2):

'^'  says to start on a newline, or the start of the string(pointed out by 1_CR). So this will never match anything as long as its there.

in any case I would just use findall, and parse out the 'test' value that you didnt want afterwards.

```
re.findall(r'(.*?)\s(\$.*?)\s', data)
```

will return

```
[('Maybe Example', '$00.00'), ('test', '$00.00'), ('bla', '$00.00')]
```

Comment: not quite. [It matches the start of the string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Thanks, updated.  I usually just use findall, so I didn't consider that.